# Possible cause for "Runtime Error" in the following code?

Tags: c++, windows, algorithm

I'm currently practising the kickstart coding challenges by google. here is a link to see the question :
https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000050e01/00000000000698d6
I have made the program which succeeded giving the right answer using the sample question which the question provided but when I actually submit it for checking, the code met a runtime error. Since it won't give why so, I have no idea how to proceed. So I hope you guys can help...

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ts;
    cin >> ts;
    for (int i = 1; i <= ts; ++i)
    {
        int n, p;
        cin >> n >> p;

        // input skill level and sort descending
        int skill[100] = {0};
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> skill[i];
        int size = sizeof(skill) / sizeof(skill[0]);
        sort(skill, skill + size, greater<int>());

        int ans= 9999999;
        for (int i = 0; i <=(n-p); i++)
        {
            int tmp = 0;
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= i + (p - 1); j++)
                tmp += skill[i] - skill[j];
            ans = min(ans, tmp);
        }
        cout << "Case #" << i << ": " << ans << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So the question says that `N` can be upto 10000, but your code assumes that it is no bigger than 100.

Comment: Thank you. With your help I have passed the first test case but the second one resulted in Time Limit Exceeded error. Do you have any idea how to pass this problem? Like if there is inefficiency you can point out in the code or the entire method I used is inefficient itself ?

Comment: it wont happen since I already sort the array from greater to smaller. But thanks for the advice.. Much appreciated.

Comment: @ProgrammerNoob Yes I missed that,

Comment: ***one resulted in Time Limit Exceeded error*** TLE means your algorithm probably needs to be rewritten completely.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding LTE, you are almost there. Try to replace the

```
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= i + (p - 1); j++)
            tmp += skill[i] - skill[j];
```

loop with the constant time expression. Hint: when the most skillful player leaves the window, by how much the training time for the rest players gets decreased?